# How to do Nagios check_ping for secondary IP in server?

Tags: ping, nagios

I have a CentOS 7 server with two IPs each on interfaces eth0 and eth1. I want to check the ping status with Nagios for both IPs separately because, each IP is used for different purpose and in different VLANs.

I tried using check_ping for both IPs, but it doesn't show secondary IP status correctly. Even if the eth1 interface IP is down, it shows ping status OK.

I see that check_ping plugin has an option as below

```
/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_ping -H <eth1interfaceIP> -w 1000.0,10% -c 3000.0,50%
```

But how to implement that in host configuration file in Nagios server without agent being installed in client?

Comment: So you wanna have 2 two checks, each one for different IP and you want check ping initialized from your Nagios server, it is correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this. Adding "**custom variable macros**" would help here. Macros of this type are distinguished from standard being necessarily prefixed by a "_" symbol.

Steps:

1.Add the command definition using the variable as below, in the global commands.cfg file of Nagios server. The custom variable macros are **_HOSTSECONDIP, _HOSTTHIRDIP** in below code

```
define command{
        command_name    check-host-alive
        command_line    $USER1$/check_ping -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 5
        }


define command{
        command_name    check-second-ip
        command_line    $USER1$/check_ping -H $_HOSTSECONDIP$ -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 5
        }

define command{
        command_name    check-third-ip
        command_line    $USER1$/check_ping -H $_HOSTTHIRDIP$ -w 3000.0,80% -c 5000.0,100% -p 5
        }
```

2.Add the secondary IP configuration for the server in server config file inside Nagios server

```
define host {
    use         linux-server
    host_name   hostname
    alias       hostname
    address     IP1
    _SECONDIP   IP2
    _THIRDIP    IP3
    icon_image      win40.png
    icon_image_alt  Windows
    vrml_image      win40.png
    statusmap_image win40.png
    }

define service{
    use                     generic-service
    host_name               hostname
    service_description     Ping-IP1
    check_command           check_ping!1000.0,10%!3000.0,50%
    }
define service{
    use                     linux-service
    host_name               hostname
    service_description     Ping-IP2
    check_command           check-second-ip!IP2!1000.0,10%!3000.0,50%
    }
define service{
    use                     linux-service
    host_name               hostname
    service_description     Ping-IP3
    check_command           check-third-ip!IP3!1000.0,10%!3000.0,50%
    }
```

3.Restart Nagios server

```
service nagios restart
```